# How would I convert this Ruby hash to an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this data in a hash:

```
[{"total_time"=>"00:04:48.563044"}, {"total_time"=>"00:05:29.835918"}, {"total_time"=>"00:09:38.622569"}]
```

But I want this:

```
["00:04:48.563044", "00:05:29.835918", "00:09:38.622569"]
```

Needs to work with Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might manage with this:

```
list.collect(&:values).flatten
```

Comment: `collect` is the same as `map` for those less familiar with Ruby.  Also, `collect!` or `map!` is available to mutate the object instead of creating a new one.

Comment: A `map` call might be simpler in this very specific case, but that snippet I posted is a general pattern that works in a wide variety of circumstances. This is the "give me the values from multiple hashes in a single dimensional array" method.

Answer (score 3):

There's a ton of ways to accomplish this. Let's break it down into the basic steps you need to accomplish:

1. Iterate over each item in the array of hashes
2. For each item, grab the time value
3. Reassemble those into a list

Since you want to grab the result for each item, not just look at it, you'll want to use `map` (or `collect`, they're actuality the same method). That will take care of steps 1 and 3. And step 2, by itself, is pretty easy. You just need to get the value for a key with `item['total_time']`. Put it all together, and you've got this:

```
times.map{ |time| time['total_time'] }
```

Comment: there a tons of ways, but I'd say this is the reasonable. Maybe a one-liner with  { } instead of do/end in this case? it looks a bit weird for code so short.

Comment: Yep, the multi-line syntax was an leftover from revision while I was writing. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about a ton of ways to accomplish this:

```
a = [{"total_time"=>"00:04:48.563044"}, {"total_time"=>"00:05:29.835918"}, {"total_time"=>"00:09:38.622569"}]

p a.map(&:flatten).map(&:last)
```

Comment: @undur_gongor then please take it as a curiosity